# How can i force tcp to discard the oldest data segment in the buffer and accept the new data written by the application in NS2

Tags: networking, tcp, ns2

I'm trying to adjust TCP to work well over real-time communication. To do this one of the specification is to force TCP to accept new data written by the application even when the buffer is full which makes TCP sometimes 'unreliable'. This way the applications write calls are never blocked and the timing of the sender application is not broken.
I think there must be an option in NS2 to make it possible.
So, How can I force TCP to discard the oldest data segment in the buffer and accept the new data written by the application in NS2?

Comment: Seems like you might be trying to force a square peg into a round hole.

Comment: RealTime is an often overloaded term. What exactly do you mean when you say realtime. Determinstic? Fast? Non-Blocking?

Comment: I think you may want to change this question to read: "How would I simulate TCP-RTM using/in NS2"? I would also provide a link to the TCP-RTM paper and the NS2 home page in your question. You will most likely get a better response.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot.  TCP is a "reliable stream".  Any functionality that allowed data to be dropped would be counter to that goal and so there is no such support.

If you want to be able to drop data, you're going to have to switch to something like UDP and implement your own windowing/retry if you want "mostly reliable delivery" instead of "best effort".

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to be dropping data anyway, just drop it before you send it to the socket. You can use select to see if the socket is available for writing, and if not drop the data at the application layer. If it is of the utmost importance that you have the latest freshest data, then see Brian's answer.

**Edit**

On a side note you may want to google for real time network protocols, and see what already exists.

Comment: @arefinsami: That is cool, but you have to realize that A) it is not TCP, but is TCP-RTM, and B) the changes they made were to the TCP stack, it was not done at the application level. If you want the same thing you will need to create/modify the TCP stack you are currently using.

Comment: They actually modified the transport layer protocol TCP(version:tcpreno with sack) and named it as TCP-RTM. And I'm going to simulate this in NS2. You may take a look at that thesis paper(last line of page:3). Thats what i'm trying to do.thankyou.

Comment: @arefinsami: I think we are saying the same thing. If you look here: http://gregorio.stanford.edu/sliang/ he has the source code available. Is there a reason you cannot use that directly?

Comment: @arefinsami: Do you mean this NS2 http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/ ? If yes, that sort of changes the question.

Comment: yup. He actually implemented this in an old linux kernel 2.2, i mean in real environment and tested it using a voip application. But, the different is i am trying to implement this in NS2(network simulator).thankyou.